# Get post thumbnail function not working?

Tags: thumbnails

i am using this function to get child page thumbnail

```
 <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>" title="<?php echo $page->post_title ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail', 'alt="' . $page->post_title . '"'); ?></a>
```

plz help me !!

Comment: You'll need to provide more information if you want help.

Comment: actually i want to display page's title in alt image.

Answer (score 0):

use `array` in third parameter

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail', array( 'alt' => $page->post_title , 'title' => $page->post_title ) ); ?></a>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail